# Why cant I access a property of an instance from another class?

Tags: python

I've have trouble with this issue for a while now, and the following is an example of the problem:

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.weapon = "rifle"
        self.rifle_test = Rifle(self)
        self.dictionary = {}
        self.dictionary["rifle"] = self.rifle_test

    def check(self):
        print(self.weapon)
        print(self.dictionary[self.weapon].ammo)

class Rifle(object):
    def __init__(self, player):
        self.ammo = 10
        self.player = player
        self.player.check()

player_test = Player()
```

I have a player ("player_test") and a rifle ("rifle_test"). When I call check() inside Rifle(), nothing is printed in the console. I've tried moving things around, separating the two classes and not having rifle_test in player_test, etc. The main problem is this: **when I execute a function of a specific instance from another instance, the function is executed but not treated as if it were executed from the instance that carries it**. In other words, If I execute check() from Rifle(), it would be different than if I were to execute it from player_test. Is there a way to execute the function the same way as if I were to execute it from player_test? Thanks.

Comment: Further to Hamms' answer, does `Rifle` need a `player` parameter at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have some mutually-exclusive dependencies. Look closely at what happens when you execute your program:

First, you create a new player

```
player_test = Player()
```

Creating a new player means calling the `__init__` method on that class, so we do that ...

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self:
        self.weapon = "rifle"
        self.rifle_test = Rifle(self)
```

Oh! But halfway through, we create a new rifle.

```
class Rifle(object):
    def __init__(self, player):
        self.ammo = 10
        self.player = player
        self.player.check()
```

Alright, our rifle's created, and we call `self.player.check()`:

```
def check(self):
    print(self.weapon)
    print(self.dictionary[self.weapon].ammo)
```

But wait! We never finished creating the player in the first place. At this point, although `self.weapon` is defined, `self.dictionary` has actually not yet been created.

The definition of `check` that you have depends on there being an initialized `self.dictionary`, but your `self.dictionary` that you have depends on there being a defined `self.rifle_test`, which in turn depends on `check`.

This is a circular dependency, and it's not going to work; you need to redesign. I would recommend removing the call to `check()` from your Rifle's `__init__`.

Comment: *We never finished creating the player in the first place* - you nailed it!